# How to troubleshoot Audible App on Android Auto?

Tags: android-auto, audible

Sorry not sure this question is valid on this forum - please let me know, if you like me to remove it.

I am new to Android Auto, and I'm trying to get the Audible Application to work with my car.

The content (book) is already downloaded to the phone.  Once I start to play the content after about a minute or so the audio is cut off, but I can see the progress bar (seconds) tick away.  I try to stop the program from playing, but it won't respond, and continue to tick away.

If it helps

- the phone was connected using Bluetooth
- Android Auto version 9.0.630834 (on my phone)
- Phone Android Version 10
- Audible Version 3.47.0
- Audible Battery Setting: Allow Background Activity, Optimize Battery Usage is On
- Audible Permissions - No Permissions Denied

---

This morning I disabled Android Auto on my phone, and connected the car stereo to my phone using Bluetooth.

Same thing happened, I started Audible, then after a few minutes (2-3 minutes), the audio cuts off but the seconds tick away.

Comment: Some audio systems disconnect if the volume is very low. May be this automatic also the problem in your case. Does it work if you play music instead an audio book?

Comment: Thank you @Robert - it does play music for extended periods.  So the strange thing is that I can see the seconds tick by on AA, but there is no sound (the volume is not low).  Also did another experiment this morning I'll update the description in case it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The good people over at android-central provided a few hints.

It seems that it is running in a stable fashion.  Although I find my config changes to be counterintuitive:

> I do not understand this but ever since I
>
> - **disabled** Allow background activity
> - **disabled** Optimize battery usage
>
> For Audible it seems to be solid.

You can follow the entire [thread](https://forums.androidcentral.com/threads/android-auto-audible-app-unstable.1056444/post-7146123).